# Select rolling rows without a loop

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, matrix

I have a question.
Suppose I have matrix 
A =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
10    11    12
```

I need to select n rolling rows from A and transpose elements in new matrix C in rows.
The loop that I use is:

```
n = 3;     %for instance every 3 rows of A

B = []; 

for i = 1:n 

    Btemp = transpose(A(i:i+size(A,1)-n,:)); 

    B = [B;Btemp]; 

end

C=B';
```

and that produces matrix C which is:

C =

```
 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
 4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

This is what i want too do, but can I do the same job without the loop?

It takes 4 minutes to calculate for an A matrix of 3280x35 size.

Comment: how would the reshape function work in my case? I am new to MATLAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make it work very fast if you make initialization. And one other trick is to take the transpose first, since MATLAB uses columns as first index instead of rows.

```
tic
A =  reshape(1:3280*35,[3280 35])'; %# Generate an example A
[nRows, nCols] = size(A);

n = 3; %for instance every 3 rows of A
B = zeros(nRows-n+1,nCols*n);
At = A';
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    B(i,:) = reshape(At(:,i:i+n-1), [1 nCols*n]); 
end
toc
```

The elapsed time is

```
Elapsed time is 0.004059 seconds.
```

Comment: +1: @petrichor Nice one. I was just about to give a similar answer, but you got ahead of me.

Comment: ok, I am not familiar yet with the site rules, how do I do that? click "was this post useful to you?"

Answer (score 0):

I would not use reshape in the loop, but transform A first to one single row (actually a column will also work, doesn't matter)

```
Ar = reshape(A',1,[]); % the ' is important here!
```

then the selecting of elements out of Ar is really simple:

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A);
new_ncols = ncols*n;
B = zeros(nrows-(n-1),new_ncols);

for ii = 1:nrows-(n-1)
    B(ii,:) = Ar(n*(ii-1)+(1:new_ncols));
end
```

Still, the preallocation of `B`, gives you the largest improvement: more info at http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab on me right now but I think you can do this without loops like this:

```
reshape(permute(cat(A(1:end-1,:),A(2:end,:),3),[3,2,1]), [2, size(A,2)*(size(A,1) - 1)]);
```

and in fact won't this do what you want?:

```
A1 = A(1:end-1,:);
A2 = A(2:end,:);
answer = [A1(:) ; A2(:)]
```

Comment: ok, now do it for A of size `3280x35` and `n=3`. That'll keep you busy typing for a good couple of hours :)